# VBA Macro - Compare two sheets value based on Unique Ids

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

i have added two sheets images
based on order_id i need to compare both sheets Casenumber,sentence details but orders are re-arranged in both sheets how to do comparison can anyone help?

i tried to compare both sheets if value matches im highlighting as green else red

```vb
Sub CompareAndHighlight()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheets to compare
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to the appropriate sheet name
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change to the appropriate sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row in the first column (assumed to be column C)
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through the rows and compare values
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if column A is not blank
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            If ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value And _
               ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value And _
               Then
                ' Values match, so highlight cells in green
                ws1.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
                ws1.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
               
                
                ws2.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
                ws2.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
               
            Else
                ' Values don't match, so highlight cells in red
                ws1.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
                ws1.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
               
                
                ws2.Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
                ws2.Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
             
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to compare unique values, a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) (aka a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) or associative array) comes to mind.

First you'd create a Dictionary whose keys are the unique values from sheet 1 and then you can iterate through the rows of sheet 2 to find a match. There are several ways you could create the keys for the Dictionary, the simplest of which might be to concatenate the case number and sentence details.

In your example, you highlight rows in both sheet 1 and sheet 2, so you'll need to keep track of cells in sheet 1 that matched sheet 2 as you iterate through the rows in sheet 2. Then you can loop through the sheet 1 unique values and find ones that did not match.

```vb
Sub CompareAndHighlight()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sheet1UniqueEntries As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim uniqueCaseNumSentence as String
    Dim matchedSheet1Entries As New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    ' Set the worksheets to compare
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to the appropriate sheet name
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") ' Change to the appropriate sheet name

    lastRow = ws1.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        uniqueCaseNumSentence = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value & ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value
        sheet1UniqueEntries(uniqueCaseNumSentences) = i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To ws2.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
        uniqueCaseNumSentence = ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value & ws2.Cells(i, 4).Value
        If sheet1UniqueEntries.Exists(uniqueCaseNumSentence) Then
            sheet1Row = sheet1UniqueEntries(uniqueCaseNumSentence)
            HighlightGreen ws1, sheet1Row
            HighlightGreen ws2, i
            matchedSheet1Entries(uniqueCaseNumSentence) = i
        Else
            HighlightRed ws2, i
        End If
    Next i

    ' Go through sheet 1 and highlight cells without a match
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Not matchedSheet1Entries.Exists(uniqueCaseNumSentence) Then
            uniqueCaseNumSentence = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value & ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value
            HighlightRed ws1, i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To simplify the code, I assume you have two functions, `HighlightGreen` and `HighlightRed` that take as input a worksheet object and a row number and highlight the cells accordingly. Implementing these functions is left as an exercise for the reader.